# How to add new contentType in postman

Tags: azure-devops, postman

I want to send a POST which requires `-ContentType 'application/json-patch+json'`.

I have tried this

[image]

and when I check the code snippet generated by postman

```
$headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json-patch+json")
...
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=6.0' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

This invoke-restmethod is missing `-ContentType 'application/json-patch+json'` and will return 400 Bad Request

If I add it manually it will work.

```
#$headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json-patch+json")
...
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=6.0' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json-patch+json'
```

How do I add this in postman?

Answer (score 0):

You should add on Headers section (Postman) the below:

```
Content-Type --> application/json
```

[image: content-type]

Attaching also a guide for REST api triggering on Azure DevOps through POSTman

https://blog.geralexgr.com/cloud/trigger-azure-devops-build-pipelines-using-rest-api

Comment: I have tried this and got the response

"The request indicated a Content-Type of \"application/json\" for method type \"POST\" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are: application/json-patch+json."

Comment: I cannot locate a POST request on work items. As I see on the DevOps API you should use the GET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Comment: It is used with POST here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Comment: Did you try `application/json-patch+json` on Content-Type? Instead of application/json use the first one

Comment: I can get it to work as a script with post and application/json-patch+json, the issue is that postman does not work